# User Boot Mode Programming on Renesas

Tags: ide, embedded

I understand this is a specific question, but I haven't been able to find any clue even to the answer anywhere.

I have a Renesas SH7211 microcontroller on a board, and I'd like to program its User Boot MAT.
I'm using the HEW that Renesas provides, and E10A debugger(Also have FDT installed)
I have the buttons to boot it up from that MAT, but I can't find anywhere how to configure HEW so that it compiles a project for the User Boot Mode, and also can't find how to write it into the correct space. Their support suggests using the FDT, but it doesn't accept E10A as a writing tool.

Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: I initially read that as " **boat** mode ". Hehehehe. Shades of the early days.

Comment: Explanation of the above: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19487#19487

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, and several answers from Renesas support my conclusions are the following on the subject:

There is no way to write to the User Boot MAT using the debuggers, also there is no way to debug a program running in the User Boot MAT. Appearantly it's true for all the series of these processors, but don't catch me on this.

To write to the User Boot, you have to connect to the Processor in Boot Mode using RS-232 (SCIF1 Port) with the FDT (Generic Device Settings), and specify in the options of the FDT to load it to the User Boot Section.

What the support suggest regarding debug is to load the program into the regular MAT, and debug it there. This makes it quite hard to debug the Flash Writing procedures, which the User Boot MAT is for, but there's no other way currently to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the micro that you have but I think this might help you

Under "build" menu, you will see an open called Super H RISC engine Standard toolchain.  Within it, you will see a tab called "Link/Library".  Within it, you will see two pull down menus; one is "category" and the other is "show entries for".  In the category, select "Section".  There you will see the position in which the code is placed in memory.  There you modify the memory map to put your code in Boot section

Hope it helps!

Regards!

R V

Comment: Boot is a different Flash chip and is mapped starting address 0 also.